# When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 4 tables.

1 - Users
2 - UserRole
3 - Role
4 - AccessLevel

What I need is, when the user login to the application, list of access levels will be send to it .

I am using the following code to do it :

```
                var userInfo = await Users.Where(x => x.Id == id)
                 .Select(x => new
                 {
                     UserDusplayName = x.Name + x.Family,
                     AccessLevel = x.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault().Role.AccessLevels.ToList()
                 })
                 .Select(v=>new UserInformationDto
                 {
                     DispayName=v.UserDusplayName,
                     AccessUnserInfos=v.AccessLevel.Select(x=>x.Access)
                 }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

in my database this id have an AccessLevel .

However, when I send a request to this , it show me the following:

> When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type

**whats the problem with my code ? how can I solve this problem ??**

Answer (score 2):

> whats the problem with my code ?

Techically the problem is not your code which is a valid LINQ query, but EF Core query translator bugs/shortcomings.

There are two constructs here

```
AccessLevel = x.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault().Role.AccessLevels.ToList()
```

which are causing troubles with EF Core translator.

First is `ToList()` call. While it is supported in final projections (`Select`), it causes issues with further query operators like the next `Select` part

```
v.AccessLevel.Select(x=>x.Access)
```

Second is `FirstOrDefault()` here

```
x.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault().Role.AccessLevels
```

i.e. converting a sequence to single item, then taking child sequence from it.

> how can I solve this problem ?

First, remove `ToList()` or eliminate the intermediate `Select`. Second, remove `FirstOrDefault()` - it makes no sense, or if really needed, replace it with the equivalent set limiting operator `Take(1)`. The use the set flattening operator `SelectMany` to get to the desired subset.

e.g.

```
AccessLevel = x.UserRoles.SelectMany(ur => ur.Role.AccessLevels)
```

should solve the current problem.

---

Unrelated, but since in your model user has many roles, and role has many access levels, here

```
AccessUnserInfos = v.AccessLevel.Select(x => x.Access)
```

you can get duplicate values, so consider applying `Distinct` operator

```
AccessUnserInfos = v.AccessLevel.Select(x => x.Access).Distinct()
```